# Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails in java jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm a complete beginner in sql and I connect a java app to a mysql xampp server . Now I have 2 tables a table of customers and a table of emails .

This is a visual representation of my tables

[image]

In my java app I have a list of customer ids I want to delete  and when I run my query I get

```
Could not delete customer data java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails  (`airline_db`.`email_address`, CONSTRAINT `email_address_customer_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer` (`customer_id`))
```

My code :

```
ArrayList<String> deleteCustomers = new ArrayList<>();
 //... add values to deleteCustomers and then proceed to delete 
try {
                    for(String id : deleteCustomers) {
                        String delCustomers = "DELETE FROM customer WHERE customer_id = ?";
                        state=connection.prepareStatement(delCustomers);
                        state.setString(1, id);
                        state.executeUpdate();
                    }
                 }catch(SQLException e ) {
                     System.out.println("Could not delete customer data " +e);
                 }
```

It seems that since the email table takes the customer_id from customer as a foreign key I cannot delete a customer entry . I do not know how to deal with this and I would appreciate your help since I am a beginner .

Comment: first delete the email.

Comment: or make sure the constraint is `on delete cascade`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the customer_id is used as a foreign key in your EMail-Table, you cannot delete it. Therefore you first need to delete all emails that use the customer_id you want to delete, and then delete the customer_id in the Customer-Table